# Why does positive net energy mean energy loss and negative energy gain?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conventions, history

To my knowledge Work is defined as $W=-\int{\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s}}$, or in the context of vectorfields as $F=-q\nabla\Phi$ ($q=m$ in the case of gravity). Recently I have been wondering whether there is a reason why we have not decided to define Work as the additive inverse of our current definition.

Comment: I have never seen that negative sign in front of that integral. What is your source for this?

Comment: W=−∫F⃗ ⋅ds is the one-dimensional case for F=−q∇Φ

Comment: You are forgetting that we want $W=-q\Delta \Phi$. The general definition of work is $\int\mathbf F\cdot\text d\mathbf x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about work, you must ask and answer the question of *who* is doing the work, and *whose* energy change you're computing!

For example, imagine a person pushes a box that was initially at rest. For the box, it was initially at rest, and then it was moving; so clearly it gained energy. In such a situation, you need the work integral $\int \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{x}$ to come out positive, which it will do *without* the minus sign in front.

But the person *transferred* that energy into the box, which means they *lost* energy. Their loss of energy is (in a very idealized situation) exactly the negative of the energy gained by the box; that is, their energy change is $-\int \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{x}$.

In the case of fields, the question is: are you computing the work done *by the field* or the work done *on the object.* They will (in an ideal situation, i.e. with no other energy changes) be exact negatives of one another.

In all cases, you use physical intuition to figure out the exact sign. In the box example, we said "the box is moving now, so it must have gained energy." Textbooks tend not to be very clear about what their formula corresponds to exactly, so physical intuition is your best bet.

When doing relatively simple work calculations, I tend to totally ignore signs until the very end, then either put them in or explain what energy change I computed. In some more subtle ones, you need to keep track of relative signs between the different energy changes you're computing. But it all comes back to physical intuition.